# reindex a element of tree array php

Tags: php

I tried so much codes but this one gave me a result close to what I want.
 I want to change the key of a child element in this case the second array 'eric'=>array into integer '0'=>array

```
while($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(!isset($data[$d['country']])) {
       $data[$d['country']] = array(
         'text' => $d['country'],
         'nodes' => array()  
       ); 
    }
    if(!isset($data[$d['country']]['nodes'][$d['name']])) {
        $data[$d['country']]['nodes'] = array_values($data[$d['country']]['nodes']);
        $data[$d['country']]['nodes'][$d['name']] = array(
          'text' => $d['name'],
          'nodes' => array()
        );    
     }
    array_push($data[$d['country']]['nodes'][$d['name']]['nodes'], $d['n_doc']);
}
```

but the first record with nodes does not take it .like as follow:

```
0 => Array
('text' => 'paris',
 'nodes' => Array
        ('0' => Array
                (  'text' => 'eric',
                   'nodes' => Array
                       (0 => Array
                           (
                            'text' => 'so.png',              
                           ),
                        1 => Array
                           (
                            'text' => 'dd.png',              
                           ),
                        2 => Array
                           (
                            'text' => 'dd.png',              
                           ),
                       ),
                ),
        ),
            ('charl' => Array
                (  'text' => 'charl',
                   'nodes' => Array
                       (0 => Array
                           (
                            'text' => 'so.png',              
                           ),
                       ),
                ),
        ),
),
```

anyone can tell me where is the problem.
 i want have array like this :

```
0 => Array
('text' => 'paris',
 'nodes' => Array
        ('0' => Array
                (  'text' => 'eric',
                   'nodes' => Array
                       (0 => Array
                           (
                            'text' => 'so.png',              
                           ),
                        1 => Array
                           (
                            'text' => 'dd.png',              
                           ),
                        2 => Array
                           (
                            'text' => 'so.png',              
                           ),
                       ),
                ),
        ),
      ('1' => Array
                (  'text' => 'charl',
                   'nodes' => Array
                       (0 => Array
                           (
                            'text' => 'so.png',              
                           ),
                       ),
                ),
        ),
),
```

Comment: Usually it's the person who asks the question that describes the problem. But I'm up for a change.

Comment: What is your expected output? Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Most helpful would be to see a sample of the _input_ data, and then a sample of the _desired_ output.

Comment: I add in my post the expected output

Comment: I posted an answer after a lot of confusion of your expected output, hope this helps.

Comment: So the only difference is the key of the second node, which is char1 in yout output and 1 in the desired version

Comment: @Paflow I think he literally just wants to replace the `text` key in all the child arrays so there is no duplicate country names. Ie, `Paris => Paris` should be `Paris => 0`. But like @Andreas said, he should be describing the problem not us lol

Comment: no Jaquarh it's the opposite, I want to change the keys of all the elements in int 0-1-2, I want to replace 'paris' => array by 1 => array

Comment: yes Paflow when I added this line:$data[$d['country']]['nodes'] = array_values($data[$d['country']]['nodes']);
he converted me every child except the last, and I did not understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use array_map() on the key nodes after looping through each country. We can then use they array_search() on the array_keys() to find the position of the node 'text' to make it numerical.

> [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/pARff).

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($data) -1; $i++) { # This loops through each country
    $data[$i]['nodes'] = array_map(function($node) use($data, $i) { # This preserves the parent text value
        return array(
            'text'  => array_search($node['text'], array_keys($data[$i]['nodes'])), # This replaces the text with a numerical value
            'nodes' => $node['nodes'] # Preserve this
        );
    }, $data[$i]['nodes']);
}
```

> Output
>
> ```
> [ ... => [ text => Paris, nodes => [ text => 0, ... ] ... ] ... ]
> ```

**Update:** To change all of the child keys to numeric values, you can simply just use array_values()

> [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/b996t)

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($data) -1; $i++) {
    $data[$i]['nodes'] = array_map(function($nodes) {
        $newArr = array($nodes['text']);
        array_push($newArr, array_values($nodes['nodes']));
        return $newArr;
    }, $data[$i]['nodes']);
}
```

> Output
>
> ```
> [ ... => [ text => Paris, nodes => [ 0 => Paris, 1 => [ ... ] ] ... ] ... ]
> ```

Output replaces the names with numeric values whilst preserving the parent name.

Comment: I do not want to change the value of "text", I want to change the value of the array that envelope 'text', 'nodes'

Comment: Value of the array? That makes no sense, can you please explain further? An array has multiple values @hananeazee

Comment: for the form output, I have no choice I must respect it to display it in a treeview so the children's keys of the array must be int no string

Comment: so why can you not use `array_values()` to convert the keys numerically as you loop the array to output a treeview? @hananeazee

Comment: You can use my solution, just change `return array(...)` to `return array_values($node)` which will remove the `text` and `nodes` keys replacing them with numeric values 0, 1. [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/p1t1C) @hananeazee

Comment: I did it in the code above but the problem is in the last record it keeps it as it is  Jaquarh

Comment: when I do my tests the pb is at the moment when we pass to a new 'country' the array treats it as empty so it does not apply the function array_value.

Comment: Check it is `!empty()` in that case then @hananeazee

Comment: Without your exact environment, ( meaning expected inputs and outputs ) we cannot help you any further.

Comment: in my first message I gave the desired result and what I got as a result now and my php code, i have no space here to reinsert it

Comment: You did not declare your expected input, so far, we can only go off your expected output. You can always **update** your question to provide extra information @hananeazee

Comment: if you mean by input my database, it's like this :  i work with mysql database like this:
id, country, name, doc:
0, paris, qwert, qq.doc.
1, paris, eric, rr.doc.
2, paris, eric, oo.pdf.
3, london, jacque, pp.pdf.

Comment: What I am explaining is, the example of data you have given, this works for. If you have other examples of data, then you need to provide us with this in order for us to help. Consider marking this answer and then making a new question with your next problem.

Comment: it's the result of my request:0=>array(
 0=>array(
   text:'paris'
   nodes:array(
     0=>array(
        text:'quert'
        nodes:array(
          0=>qq.doc
        )
    eric=>array(
        text:'eric'
        nodes:array(
          0=>rr.doc
          1=>oo.pdf
        )    
     )
   )
 )
  1=>array(
     text:'paris'
     nodes:array(
          quert=>array(
             text:'quert'
             nodes:array(
                  0=>qq.doc
              )) ) )

Comment: the result I want to get:0=>array(
 0=>array(
   text:'paris'
   nodes:array(
     0=>array(
        text:'quert'
        nodes:array(
          0=>qq.doc
        )
    1=>array(
        text:'eric'
        nodes:array(
          0=>rr.doc
          1=>oo.pdf
        )    
     )
   )
 )
  1=>array(
     text:'paris'
     nodes:array(
          0=>array(
             text:'quert'
             nodes:array(
                  0=>qq.doc
              )
         )
     ) 
)

Comment: how to mark this answer  i'm new in this forum ,it's the flag next to?

Comment: I have updated my answer where it says **update** with a new live demo. This will do it for every child element in the array for 'nodes' - hope this helps. And yes, next to my answer there is an upvote button and a tick. press the tick. @hananeazee

Comment: I do not know I have the loop overflowing, do I have to add another loop you can not modify my loop while it works

Comment: no idea for my code

Comment: If you have more inner nodes, use foreach $nodes and $node and push the array_values() of them or make it a function and recall the function with the new array